# Activity force destroyed after choose picture

Tags: android

I have a simple `choose image source` dialog :

```
public void toggleImagePicker()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Gallery", "Camera"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            //                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");

                    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Picture");
                    if (mBackgroundClicked)
                        startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE_FOR_BACKGROUND);
                    else
                        startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

                    File cameraFolder;

                    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                        cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".helper/");
                    else
                        cameraFolder = getActivity().getCacheDir();
                    if (!cameraFolder.exists())
                        cameraFolder.mkdirs();

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
                    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                    String imageFileName = "picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

                    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".helper/" + imageFileName);
                    if (!mBackgroundClicked)
                        mProfilePhotoPath = new String(photo.getAbsolutePath());
                    else
                        mBackgroundPhotoPath = new String(photo.getAbsolutePath());
                    getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                    //                                initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                    if (mBackgroundClicked)
                        startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_FOR_BACKGROUND);
                    else
                        startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

And i try to pick image, i show the dialog and click on Camera or Gallery. Otherwise my activity is destroyed and recreated.

> No exceptions in LogCat.

Single thing what i found in logs :

```
06-11 14:45:57.700      458-549/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '221e47c0 ******.ProfileExpertActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
```

Note : pick mechanism implemented in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no application to handle the action then it will results the `NullPointerException` before starting the check with  [resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)) to check whether there are any application to handle it or not.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
// Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
if (photoPickerIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_PICKER);    
}
```

Comment: Pick Activity launches normally. My activity recreates when i pick image.